# PL/SQL triggers won't run

Tags: oracle, plsql, weblogic, oracleforms

I have an Oracle Forms 11 g application running on Weblogic server. The default form/login page has a few PL/SQL triggers that simply will not fire. The rest of the configuration seems successful.

Can anyone give me pointers as to where to start looking?? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just tell us which triggers are not firing.

Answer (score 1):

As their name suggests, *triggers* fire when something triggers them. For example,

- a `WHEN-BUTTON-PRESSED` trigger is triggered by pushing a button
- a `POST-QUERY` trigger fires after executing a query in a data block
- a `WHEN-NEW-FORM-INSTANCE` trigger fires when the form is being run

and so on.

Therefore, make sure that triggers really are triggered. The fact that you have them doesn't mean that they'll run, *just because*.

In order to find that out, you have two options:

- run a form in debug mode:

  - in one of the triggers (for example in a `WHEN-NEW-FORM-INSTANCE`) set a breakpoint by right clicking its left margin (you'll see what to do next)
  - then run the form; that green toolbar icon you use to run it shouldn't be used, but the one next to it, with something *reddish* on it
  - as soon as execution gets to the breakpoint, it'll stop, you'll be transferred to Forms Builder, a debug console will open and will let you navigate through the rest of the code step-by-step
  - do that, and you'll know what's going on, i.e. whether those triggers are called and what they do

    - as of you being suspicious: did you, by any chance, put some exception handlers that use `WHEN OTHERS THEN NULL` or something similar? If so, get rid of them. Even if an exception is raised (such as `NO_DATA_FOUND` or `TOO_MANY_ROWS`, just to mention two of the most *popular* and frequent ones), `THEN NULL` will silently mask it
- another one is to put `MESSAGE` calls into the triggers, such as

  ```
  begin
    message('running WBP trigger: step 1');
    ... the rest of your code goes here
  end;
  ```

  Doing so, message-after-message will raise an "alert" on the screen (as you'll have to click OK that you saw what it said), and you'll quickly see which triggers fired and which did not. Then investigate it further - debugging described previously will help.

If none of that helps, you'll have to describe what's going on, but this time providing some more info. What you wrote isn't very descriptive. Anyway, best of luck.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your detailed response little foot. I can provide as much detail required. It doesn't execute ANY pl sql, not even simple alerts. I should probably add background that this application works find on windows but I'm testing it on a centos 7 server. Let me know what other details you'd like to know, env files formsweb.cfg etc, any suggestions greatly appreciated

Comment: You're welcome. I think I don't need any further details. Moreover, I'm a Windows guy and have no idea about Centos. What you could do is to recompile the form (Ctrl + Shift + K), create a FMX file, put it to the server and see what happens. BTW, did you run it in debug mode? What did you find out?